# Trying a UdpClient example from MS and getting an error. Why?

Tags: c#, udp

I’m trying to get two instances of my program to communicate between them. I’ve been referred to udp, and so I’m trying to run the example from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx 
But I get an error:
"socketexception (0x80004005): This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution..."

how do I solve this?

I don’t know anything about this stuff. I googled for what I needed and found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687868/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets-between-two-programs-on-the-same-computer):

```
//This is how you do it (kudos to sipwiz)
    UdpClient udpServer = new UdpClient(localpt); //This is what the proprietary(see question) sender would do (nothing special) 

    //!!! The following 3 lines is what the poster needs...(and the definition of localpt (of course))
    UdpClient udpServer2 = new UdpClient();
    udpServer2.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
    udpServer2.Client.Bind(localpt);
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the minimum code to produce the issue? Are you connecting via a hostname? Is it set up?

Comment: PS: 0x80004005 is NOT a socket error.  It looks like an ActiveX/COM error.  Q: Are you sure your Windows version and/or .Net version matches the minimum requirements in the link you posted (e.g. XP SP3 or higher and .Net 3.5 SP1 or higher)?

Comment: @TheCodeKing My code is copied and pasted from the above web page. My system is Windows 7.

Comment: But you must have modified it, the code won't work as is, as it's pointing to a non-existant server. Maybe this is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are using the code for the sample unmodified.

This is trying to connect to `AlternateHostMachineName` which does not exist, and therefore throws a `0x80004005: No such host is known` exception.

You need to amend the code to connect to a real server.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are refering to hostnames that can't be resolved and/or your network settings (esp. DNS) are are somehow wrong...

The example you refer to contains two hostnames `www.contoso.com` and `AlternateHostMachineName` - both are not resolvable since they don't exist... you need to replace them with real hostnames or IP adresses and make sure that your DNS settings are correct/working...