# Communication between two programs on same computer – How?

Tags: c#, udp

I don’t know how to begin. After Googling, I’ve found this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687868/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets-between-two-programs-on-the-same-computer):

```
//This is how you do it (kudos to sipwiz)
UdpClient udpServer = new UdpClient(localpt); 

//This is what the proprietary (see question) sender would do (nothing special) 
//!!! The following 3 lines is what the poster needs...
//(and the definition of localpt, of course)
UdpClient udpServer2 = new UdpClient();
udpServer2.Client.SetSocketOption(
    SocketOptionLevel.Socket,
    SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);

udpServer2.Client.Bind(localpt);
```

But I don’t know what else I need. I tried an example from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/BetterUdpClient.htm), but got an error message: *"An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."*

How do I proceed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd suggest ditching UDP. Instead, use [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx).

They are more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use WCF with Named Pipe binding

Answer (score 0):

Named pipe is the best option on the same system.
Due the fact that the performance is better then TCP cause the traffic is not using the network interfaces.