# C# P2P without port/forwarding

Tags: c#, network-programming, port, p2p

I have made a server and client app which connects to each other, however I have to open ports in my router to make it work.

Are there any ports that I can use which doesn't require forwarding?
Or a technique I can apply?

I want to keep it p2p and avoid having a server in the middle of requests.

Answer (score 2):

I know of two techniques that could be applied here.

**Technique 1**
*UDP Hole Punching*

UDP Hole Punching uses a server as a "lobby".
The clients you want to engage a P2P connection with first connect to the server using the UDP protocol, the clients therefor require a port to be opened ("hole") to be able to receive data.

Because UDP is a connection-less protocol you can set the clients up to accept packets incoming from the "lobby"-server and each other.

After both clients have established connection the server will provide them with their partner's IP and matching "hole"-port.

A pretty straight-forward implementation can be found in the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140450/udp-hole-punching-implementation).

**Technique 2**
*Universal Plug-n-Play*

My least favourite of the two, as it requires the clients' routers to have uPnP support and to have it enabled.

uPnP in C#.NET can be easily done by including the NATUPNPLib COM-library
(don't forget to disable "Embed Interop Types" in the Reference settings)

A simple implementation would be like this:

```cs
    public const int upnp_port = 3075;

    private static UPnPNATClass pnp = new UPnPNATClass();
    private static IStaticPortMappingCollection mapc = pnp.StaticPortMappingCollection;

    public static IPAddress local_ip()
    {
        foreach (IPAddress addr in Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList)
            if (addr.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                return addr;
        return null;
    }

    public static void upnp_open()
    {
        mapc.Add(upnp_port, "UDP", upnp_port, local_ip().ToString(), true, "P2P Service Name");
    }

    public static void upnp_close()
    {
        mapc.Remove(upnp_port, "UDP");
    }
```

**PLEASE** take note that this is quickly-written code and it will need overlooking/optimisation, definitely the `local_ip()` function as it can become unreliable with several network adapters installed.