# Client - Server on same machine using UDP

Tags: c#, udp

I am trying to simulate a Client - Server scenario on my machine in c#. But when i am executing it an exception pops up saying:

> No such host is known

My code:

```
namespace TCPClient
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(args[0], 2055);
            IPEndPoint ep = null;
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Name: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                if (name == "") break;
                byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
                udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);
                byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
                string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
                Console.WriteLine(job);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

thanks Dev's ! your answers were helpful, however I found an easiest way for the same.

```
 public class Program
 {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient( System.Net.Dns.GetHostName(), 2055);
        IPEndPoint ep = null;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (name == "") break;
            byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
            udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);
            byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
            string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
            Console.WriteLine(job);
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Isolate the issue. You're calling `new UdpClient(args[0], 2055)` and `udpc.Receive(ref ep)` that can throw this exception, but don't say which one does. Either debug it or try it with a constant string:

```
string host = args[0];
new UdpClient(host, 2055);
```

You'll then see that `host` is most probably not an existing hostname. If it is, check what you are doing with `ep`: nothing, so it will be `null`. I guess you'll want to listen to any UDP datagram [as explained in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.udpclient.receive%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), so specify the endpoint:

```
ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do believe your issue lies within this call:

```
byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep)
```

The problem is that, in order to be able to listen to any incoming content, you need first to bind the UdpClient to a valid endpoint - like this:

```
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8192);
//You will be listening to port 8192.
```

Also, keep in mind that you can't both listen AND emit from the same UdpClient; You'll need two clients, and if you want to use the same IP Port for both, you'll need to initialize the class using the `SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress` parameter. A good example is provided on the following post:

[Connecting two UDP clients to one port (Send and Receive)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9120050/connecting-two-udp-clients-to-one-port-send-and-receive)