# Using NAudio over TCP?

Tags: c#, .net, tcp, tcpclient, naudio

I am looking at the demo projects for the NAUDIO library located here:

http://naudio.codeplex.com/

They have an example for Network streaming that is currently running over UDP.  I am wondering what I would need to do to convert to run over TCP.  I need this to run over TCP to ensure that each packet arrives at the server:

```
private void Connect(IPEndPoint endPoint, int inputDeviceNumber, INetworkChatCodec codec)
        {
            waveIn = new WaveIn();
            waveIn.BufferMilliseconds = 50;
            waveIn.DeviceNumber = inputDeviceNumber;
            waveIn.WaveFormat = codec.RecordFormat;
            waveIn.DataAvailable += waveIn_DataAvailable;
            waveIn.StartRecording();

            udpSender = new UdpClient();
            udpListener = new UdpClient();
            //endPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 7080);
            // To allow us to talk to ourselves for test purposes:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687868/sending-and-receiving-udp-packets-between-two-programs-on-the-same-computer
            //udpSender.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            udpListener.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
            //udpSender.Client.Bind(endPoint);
            udpListener.Client.Bind(endPoint);

            udpSender.Connect(endPoint);

            waveOut = new WaveOut();
            waveProvider = new BufferedWaveProvider(codec.RecordFormat);
            waveOut.Init(waveProvider);
            waveOut.Play();

            connected = true;
            ListenerThreadState state = new ListenerThreadState() { Codec = codec, EndPoint = endPoint };
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(this.ListenerThread, state);
        }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What part do you need help with? Check out the `System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient` which is just a higher level wrapper over `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`. However I would recommend staying with UDP for VOIP applications.

Comment: I'm not sure how to send & receive the byte[] via TCP.  I know that I will need to use TCP because I will be recording the audio on the server side.

Comment: Here are some links that might help
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.aspx
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx6588te.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a.aspx